# Is there any way to speed up the load time of the Quill HTML Editor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, quill

I'm using the QuillHtmlEditor package in my flutter app, and whenever I navigate to the page with the editor, it takes around 200-500ms for the text editor to load. Is there any way to speed up the load time so it is invisible to the user?

This is how I am instantiating it:

```
QuillHtmlEditor(
                controller: controller,
                isEnabled: widget.enabled,
                ensureVisible: false,
                minHeight: 500,
                autoFocus: false,
                textStyle: widget.editorTextStyle,
                hintTextStyle: _hintTextStyle,
                hintTextAlign: TextAlign.start,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                hintTextPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
                onEditingComplete: (s) => debugPrint('Editing completed $s'),
                loadingBuilder: (context) {
                  return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ));
                },
                onTextChanged: (text) => debugPrint('widget text change $text'),
                onEditorCreated: () {
                  debugPrint('Editor has been loaded');
                  setHtmlText(widget.controller?.text ?? '');
                },
                onEditorResized: (height) =>
                    debugPrint('Editor resized $height'),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as official plugin's page says, your implementation is correct and the loadingBuilder should be responsible of showing the progress indicator while data is loading.
But if those 500ms are still a problem, let's get through some steps.

### **1. Did you test speed in profile/release mode?**

Loading speeds in debug mode are WAY slower than profile/release mode, for obvious testing reason. Some heavy widgets and plugins can perform worse in debug, but still be fast and ready in production.

### **2. Did you test in real device?**

For quite the same reason of debug mode, if you're developing for mobile, the Android/iOS emulator is significantly slower than a real device scenario, as we're emulating different architecture.

### **3a. UI Trick: "I'm not slow, i'm elegant" way**

If some elements of UI require a little time after they've loaded to show correctly, you can use a trick for the final user: You can "fade out" a loading indicator.

With `FadeTransition` ([API here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeTransition-class.html)) or `AnimatedOpacity` ([API here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedOpacity-class.html)), and a boolean variable like `_isHtmlEditorLoaded`, you can use an animation to "slow down" the loading page dismissal:

```dart
AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _isHtmlEditorLoaded ? 0 : 1,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(...),
)
```

or, better, you can also "slow down" the editor showing:

```dart
AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _isHtmlEditorLoaded ? 1 : 0,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    child: QuillHtmlEditor(...),
)
```

### **3b. UI Trick: "007: License to preload" way**

If we know that some heavy UI elements could be used quite a lot, you can trick the user by "preloading" the Html editor without showing it.

For example, if your use case is a web browser that can edit the HTML pages, you can use the `Opacity`([API here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html)) class to hide the editor in a `Stack`([API here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)), while still is in the widget subtree:

```dart
bool _showEditor = false;

...

Stack(
  children: [
     Opacity(
       opacity: _showEditor ? 0.0 : 1.0,
       child: InAppBrowser(...),
     ),
     Opacity(
       opacity: _showEditor ? 1.0 : 0.0,
       child: QuillHtmlEditor(...),
     ),
  ]
)

...

void toggleHtmlEditor() {
  setState(() {
    _showEditor = !_showEditor;
  });
}
```

with the downside that, obviously, the whole initial parent widget loading is slower. But if it's managed, than no problems.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response! I've been debugging on a real device as well as releasing builds to TestFlight. My current plan if I couldn't find another approach was to use an indexedstack similar to your final suggestion. I wish flutter had a way to more simply preload a route.

Comment: @bf8 well, Flutter is designed to be responsive and "cheap" in terms of memory and widget tree size. Here I think it's a QuillHtmlEditor responsibility to make the plugin more responsive and usable, with more asynchronous operations and data management